# Get coordinates of text of scanned image using Microsoft OCR

Tags: c#, computer-vision, microsoft-ocr

Trying to find coordinates of text in scanned images. Scanned image has many text data need to convert that image data to text and then get the coordinates of text.Coordinates represents boundingboxes such as X,Y Axis,Height and Width where text is

**Using Microsoft OCR ProjectOxford Vision**

```
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace TextExtraction
 {
 class Program
 {  
    const string API_key = "<<Key>>";
    const string API_location = 
    "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0"; 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string imgToAnalyze = @"C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\image.jpg";
        HandwritingExtraction(imgToAnalyze, false);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PrintResults(string[] res)
    {
        foreach (string r in res)
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void HandwritingExtraction(string fname, bool wrds)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            string[] res = await HandwritingExtractionCore(fname, wrds);
            PrintResults(res);

        }).Wait();
    }

    public static async Task<string[]> HandwritingExtractionCore(string fname, bool wrds)
    {
        VisionServiceClient client = new VisionServiceClient(API_key, API_location);
        string[] textres = null;

        if (File.Exists(fname))
            using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fname))
            {
                HandwritingRecognitionOperation op = await 
         client.CreateHandwritingRecognitionOperationAsync(stream);
                HandwritingRecognitionOperationResult res = await 
         client.GetHandwritingRecognitionOperationResultAsync(op);

                textres = GetExtracted(res, wrds);
            }

        return textres;
    }

    public static string[] GetExtracted(HandwritingRecognitionOperationResult res, bool wrds)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        foreach (HandwritingTextLine l in res.RecognitionResult.Lines)
            if (wrds)
                items.AddRange(GetWords(l));
            else
                items.Add(GetLineAsString(l));

        return items.ToArray();
    }

    public static List<string> GetWords(HandwritingTextLine line)
    {
        List<string> words = new List<string>();

        foreach (HandwritingTextWord w in line.Words)
            words.Add(w.Text);

        return words;
    }

    public static string GetLineAsString(HandwritingTextLine line)
    {
        List<string> words = GetWords(line);
        return words.Count > 0 ? string.Join(" ", words) : string.Empty;
    }
}
}
```

**Expected Output :**
Get Text with their respective coordinates(x,y,height,width)

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19hzH.jpg)

**Json output**

{
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "succeeded": true,
  "failed": false,
  "finished": true,
  "recognitionResults": [
    {
      "page": 1,
      "clockwiseOrientation": 359.62,
      "width": 505,
      "height": 399,
      "unit": "pixel",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": [
            224,
            58,
            380,
            57,
            381,
            74,
            225,
            75
          ],
          "text": "GOVERNMENT OF INDIA",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                229,
                59,
                321,
                58,
                320,
                75,
                229,
                75
              ],
              "text": "GOVERNMENT"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                324,
                58,
                341,
                58,
                341,
                75,
                323,
                75
              ],
              "text": "OF"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                344,
                58,
                381,
                58,
                381,
                75,
                344,
                75
              ],
              "text": "INDIA"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": [
            211,
            159,
            429,
            160,
            428,
            180,
            210,
            178
          ],
          "text": "FH faPet/ DOB: 27/07/1982",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                225,
                160,
                243,
                160,
                243,
                179,
                225,
                179
              ],
              "text": "FH"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                247,
                160,
                286,
                160,
                286,
                179,
                247,
                179
              ],
              "text": "faPet/"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                290,
                160,
                333,
                160,
                333,
                179,
                290,
                179
              ],
              "text": "DOB:"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                337,
                160,
                428,
                162,
                428,
                180,
                337,
                179
              ],
              "text": "27/07/1982"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": [
            209,
            192,
            313,
            190,
            314,
            208,
            210,
            210
          ],
          "text": "you / MALE",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                214,
                192,
                247,
                192,
                246,
                209,
                214,
                210
              ],
              "text": "you"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                254,
                192,
                260,
                192,
                260,
                209,
                254,
                209
              ],
              "text": "/"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                264,
                192,
                314,
                192,
                313,
                208,
                263,
                209
              ],
              "text": "MALE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": [
            201,
            314,
            351,
            313,
            352,
            330,
            202,
            331
          ],
          "text": "66 66 6666 6666",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                204,
                315,
                225,
                314,
                225,
                330,
                204,
                331
              ],
              "text": "66"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                229,
                314,
                251,
                314,
                251,
                330,
                229,
                330
              ],
              "text": "66"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                255,
                314,
                301,
                314,
                301,
                330,
                255,
                330
              ],
              "text": "6666"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": [
                307,
                314,
                352,
                314,
                351,
                331,
                306,
                330
              ],
              "text": "6666"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Do not [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412472/how-to-get-coordinates-of-text-from-scanned-image) a question! If you want to add to is you can always edit the question!!

Comment: @TaW OK can you help me out with the solution

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't know that library.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using Microsoft C# Azure app like thing.  Here is the detailed link to your question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text

inside the contentString. it is sth like.

```
"language": "en",
    "textAngle": -1.5000000000000335,
    "orientation": "Up",
    "regions": [
        {
            "boundingBox": "154,49,351,575",
            "lines": [
                {
                    "boundingBox": "165,49,340,117",
                    "words": [
                        {
                            "boundingBox": "165,49,63,109",
                            "text": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "boundingBox": "261,50,244,116",
                            "text": "GOAL"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
```

I did some project with Azsure C#. But your code didn`t look very familiar.

I would suggest you to see all the data format inside **textres** or **res** (in your code) I think it contains the same reference as shown in the string above

Comment: Dr Yuan i saw that example but unable to get source code of  Read both printed and handwritten text in images  on this side 
 `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/`  please let me know if you have any idea of source code of scanned image

Comment: In your code. see whats inside the    textres or res

Comment: Yuan `https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/read/core/asyncBatchAnalyze` currently i am using this api can you please suggest how can i use this  **boundingBox": [ 224, 58, 380, 57, 381, 74, 225, 75 ]**  to create rectangle

Comment: @Tony I can not open your link.  For plot bounding box, search line "   overlay.SetBinding(Border.MarginProperty, wordBoxOverlay.CreateWordPositionBinding()); " in the microsoft OCR sample  https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/OCR/cs/OcrFileImage.xaml.cs  there you should have some idea on how to use it

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that there are two different APIs for text recognition in Microsoft Cognitive Services.  Dr. Yuan's output is from the OCR [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc) which has broader language coverage, whereas Tony's output shows that he's calling the newer and improved Read [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/2afb498089f74080d7ef85eb).

Secondly, note that client SDK referenced in the code sample above, `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision`, is deprecated, and you will want to switch to the replacement `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision`, the sample for which you will find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/csharp-hand-text-sdk).

And finally, the answer to the specific question.  The location of text recognized in your document is represented in the `boundingBox` field.  So for your example output JSON, the line of text `GOVERNMENT OF INDIA` is bounded by the coordinates (224, 58), (380, 57), (381, 74) and (225, 75), representing the four corners.  It is not in a `x,y,width,height` format to allow for rotation.  Note that the units for the bounding box is also included in the JSON (in your case, pixels).  The location of each word within the line are also in your response JSON if that's what you're after.

Comment: currently i am getting  boundingBox": [ 224, 58, 380, 57, 381, 74, 225, 75 ] as response need to convert it to create rectangle(x,y,height,width) please suggest how can i achieve this

Comment: var xval = line.BoundingBox.Where((v,i) => (i&1) == 0);
    var yval = line.BoundingBox.Where((v,i) => (i&1) == 1);
    var x = xval.Min();
    var y = yval.Min();
    var width = xval.Max() - x;
    var height = yval.Max() - y;
    var rect = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);

Comment: Can you help me out to for this parameters boundingBox":[X top left,Y top left,X top right ,Y top  right ,  X bottom right , Y bottom right ,X bottom left, Y bottom left ] since i have this points . What are v,i value ?

Comment: v,i are values auto-assigned in the Linq statement, v in this case is the value, i the index.

Comment: i have boundingBox":[X top left,Y top left,X top right ,Y top right , X bottom right , Y bottom right ,X bottom left, Y bottom left ] value by using this how can i create rectangle box as i can see you have used line